# Can Html Agility Pack target an element based on name attribute?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), is it possible to target a specific element value by looking for it's name attribute, instead of its index position in the list of nodes? For example, how would the element with `name="description"` be targeted if the order of form elements changed, and to check if it even exists within the form?

Example HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="example">
    <input type="hidden" name="body" value="example">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="example">
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="example">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="example">
</form
```

C# that targets elements by index number. This fails because not all HTML files have the form elements in the same order, and sometimes the input elements are missing:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);
var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
var elements = form.SelectNodes("//input");

MyObject Obj = new MyObject();
Obj.Title = elements[0].Attributes["value"].Value;
Obj.Body = elements[1].Attributes["value"].Value;
Obj.Description = elements[2].Attributes["value"].Value;
Obj.Category = elements[3].Attributes["value"].Value;
Obj.Date = elements[4].Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the use of XPaths in Html-Agility-Pack, you can search for almost anything within the html document.

XPath you are using looks up the entire `form` or list of `inputs` but you are not looking for a specific thing.

If you need a specific element that has the attribute, `name` that holds the value of `description`, you can use the following xpath to look it up.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);

var inputNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='description']");

if (inputNode == null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Empty Gift Box"); // nothing found.
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine(inputNode.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString());
}
// Prints 'example'

// Or you can use a single line lookup and assignment.
// Note.. ?. means if the result was null / not found, set left side = null.
Obj.Title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='title']")?.Attributes["value"]?.Value.ToString();
```

**How does it work**

`//` searches the entire document
`/` looks for the tag immediately after the tag before it (//form/input). If there was another tag between form and input, this would yield 0 results.
`.//` searches for any tag under specific tag you are calling SelectNodes on. if there are input tags outside of , they will not be captured under grandChild.

```
var parentNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form");
var grandChild = parentNode.SelectNodes(".//input"); // must be part of form.
```

if you are searching for a specific index of input, or attribute or value, you can use the keyword search,

```
// Get any first node that has both name and value
var specificNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name and @value]");  

// Get first node that has specific name and value
var specificNode2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='description' and @value='example']");

// Get 3rd input element
var thirdInput = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[3]");
```

There are many other ways of searching within the document, but this should get you squared away. Do make sure you read up on [HAP Documentation.](https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation) and many answers already available on StackOverflow under [Html-Agility-Pack tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack?sort=Newest&uqlId=13143)

*Dont forget to mark the post that answers your post as an answer.*